# sorting data using key in python

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics, protein-database

I got a data format like:

```
ATOM 124 N GLU B 12
ATOM 125 O GLU B 12
ATOM 126 OE1 GLU B 12
ATOM 127 C GLU B 12
ATOM 128 O GLU B 14
ATOM 129 N GLU B 14
ATOM 130 OE1 GLU B 14
ATOM 131 OE2 GLU B 14
ATOM 132 CA GLU B 14
ATOM 133 C GLU B 15
ATOM 134 CA GLU B 15
ATOM 135 OE2 GLU B 15
ATOM 136 O GLU B 15
             .....100+ lines
```

From here, I want to  filter this data based on `col[5]` (starting column count from 0) and `col[2]`. Per `value` of `col[5]` if `OE1` or `OE2` happens to be only once then the data set to be discarded. But for each value of `col[5]` if `OE1` and `OE2` both be present, it would be kept.
The desired data after filtering:

```
ATOM 128 O GLU B 14
ATOM 129 N GLU B 14
ATOM 130 OE1 GLU B 14
ATOM 131 OE2 GLU B 14
ATOM 132 CA GLU B 14
```

I have tried using `search_string` like:

```
for item in stored_list:
    search_str_a = 'OE1'+item[3]+item[4]+item[5]
    search_str_b = 'OE2'+item[3]+item[4]+item[5]
    target_str = item[2]+item[3]+item[4]+item[5]
```

This is helpful to maintain rest of the `col` alike while searching for `OE1` or `OE2`, but not helpful to filter and eliminate if one of them(or both them) is missing.

Any ideas would be really nice here.

Comment: So did you want to keep `col[5]=14`?

Comment: for a single value of `col[5]` we need to search `col[3]` and after making decisions regarding keeping data or discarding(based on  the presence of both `OE1` and `OE2`), we iterate the value of `col[5]` and keep searching same way @Avinash Raj This is my so far idea.

Comment: You should mention that you're parsing PDB files, as there *are* bioinformaticians out there. In this case, check out Biopython's [`Bio.PDB`](http://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ) module. I don't have the slightest clue what information you're trying to retrieve here, as your question is rather unclear, but reading through the linked FAQ will help you greatly.

Comment: @Kasramvd yes, as it has both `OE1` and `OE2`, as per desired output.

Comment: What I got from your question is that you want to keep lines with a special `col[5]` and unique `col[3]` right?

Comment: @ Kasramvd Precisely if both `OE1` and `OE2` belongs to a single `value` of `col[5]` then the line to be kept. If any single one of them(`OE1` or `OE2`) is missing(per value) then we discard the line.

Answer (score 2):

The below code needs pandas
you can download it from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html

```
import pandas as pd

file_read_path = "give here source file path"
df = pd.read_csv(file_read_path, sep= " ", names = ["col0","col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"])
group_series =  df.groupby("col5")["col2"].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ', '.join(x))

filtered_list = []
for index in group_series.index:
    str_col2_group = group_series[index]
    if "OE1" in str_col2_group and "OE2" in str_col2_group:
        filtered_list.append(index)

df = df[df.col5.isin(filtered_list)]
output_file_path = "give here output file path"
df.to_csv(output_file_path,sep = " ",index = False,header = False)
```

this would be helpfull http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Output result

```
ATOM 128 O GLU B 14
ATOM 129 N GLU B 14
ATOM 130 OE1 GLU B 14
ATOM 131 OE2 GLU B 14
ATOM 132 CA GLU B 14
```

Comment: much appreciated, although a bit non-panda would have been better...@Romil

Answer (score 0):

using csv, it comes with python

```
import csv
import operator

file_read_path = "give here source file path"
with open(file_read_path) as f_pdb:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f_pdb,delimiter=' ', fieldnames = ["col0","col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"])
    sorted_bio = sorted(rdr,key=operator.itemgetter('col5'),reverse=False)
    col5_tmp = None
    tmp_list = []
    perm_list = []
    tmp_str = ""
    col5_v = ""
    for row in sorted_bio:
        col5_v = row["col5"]
        if col5_v != col5_tmp:
            if "OE1" in tmp_str and "OE2" in tmp_str:
                perm_list.extend(tmp_list)
            tmp_list = []
            tmp_str = ""
            col5_tmp = col5_v
        tmp_list.append(row)
        tmp_str = tmp_str +","+ row["col2"]

    if col5_v != col5_tmp:
        if "OE1" in tmp_str and "OE2" in tmp_str:
            perm_list.extend(tmp_list)


csv_file = open("give here output file path","w")
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file,delimiter=' ', fieldnames = ["col0","col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"])
for row in perm_list:
    dict_writer.writerow(row)
csv_file.close()
```